# Nested Loop in Ruby, Hash and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, object, hash

How can i do this in Ruby

```js
var pCodePrice = {
  'GR1': 3.11,
  'SR1': 5,
  'CF1': 11.23
};
var basket = ['GR1', 'SR1', 'GR1', 'GR1', 'CF1'];
var total = [];


for (i = 0, x = basket.length; i < x; i++) {
  for (var prop in pCodePrice) {
    if (basket[i] == prop) {
      total.push(pCodePrice[prop])
    }

  }

}
```

This loops through the array and checks to see if the item matches the key of the hash in the inner loop, if so it pushes the value into a new array.

I just cant get it in Ruby,

Thanks

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? That code would almost work as-is in Ruby if you made a couple minor modifications to the for loops and dropped the `var` keyword. (Though of course, there's also a much more idiomatic way of doing it.)

Comment: an array (total) that is only the prices of the items in the basket

Comment: @Ajedi32, I have tried something very similar but what happens is that instead of 'pushing' the value of the hash that corresponds to the array it just pushes all the values. I am not familiar with the syntax so dont think I am being spcific enough about the iterations? Maybe

Comment: @IainWatt If you edit the actual code Ruby code you tried into the question we can definitely help you understand what's wrong with it and what changes you would need to make it work. Without that though, your question reads kind of like "hey, port this code to Ruby for me", which some people will happily do, but doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: @Ajedi32, yes I know i was sort of asking that... sorry, will explain more with the next question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple in ruby using map.

```
pCodePrice = { 'GR1' => 3.11, 'SR1' => 5, 'CF1' => 11.23 }
 => {"GR1"=>3.11, "SR1"=>5, "CF1"=>11.23} 
basket = ['GR1','SR1','GR1','GR1','CF1']
 => ["GR1", "SR1", "GR1", "GR1", "CF1"] 
total = basket.map { |code| pCodePrice[code] }
 => [3.11, 5, 3.11, 3.11, 11.23]
```

Comment: or even more concisely `pCodePrice.values_at(*basket) #=>[3.11, 5, 3.11, 3.11, 11.23]`

Comment: engineersmnky, Thanks! I wasn't familiar with values_at. What a nice method.